# Optimization of a bottleneck operation in Julia

Tags: optimization, julia

I have a program that requires performing many simple calculations (it's actually a variant of Monte Carlo). After benchmarking, I have noticed that the following function is where my bottleneck is located.

```
function get_window_of_Aₖ(model, target , K, n_samples)
    count.([model.(rand(Normal(μ, stddev), K)') .< target(rand(Normal(μ, stddev))) for _ in 1:n_samples])
end
```

After analyzing and rewriting this function in several lines,

```
function get_window_of_Aₖ(model, target, K, n_samples)
    counts = Vector{Int}(undef, n_samples)
    for i in 1:n_samples
        model_samples = rand(Normal(μ, stddev), K)
        target_sample = rand(Normal(μ, stddev))
        @inbounds counts[i] = count(model.(model_samples) .< target(target_sample))
    end
    return counts
end
```

The real cost is found in the line `count(model.(model_samples) .< target(target_sample)).`

I have tried using `sum` instead of `count`, subtracting and checking the sign, using `SVectors`, `map`, but so far I haven't achieved satisfactory optimization. Can anyone think of a trivial optimization that I haven't seen? Also, I am not using multithreading or multiprocessing as I intend to do that in the outermost loop of the routine, which is not shown here.

On the other hand, you can consider the functions `model(x) = 3x + 10` and `target(x) = 10x + 3`, for example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got a 4x speed-up by avoiding allocations.
My setup

```
model_samples = rand(Normal(0, 1), 10_000)
target_sample = rand(Normal(0, 1))
```

Actual tests:

```
julia> @btime count(model.($model_samples) .< target($target_sample))
  6.800 μs (3 allocations: 5.55 KiB)
1248

julia> @btime sum( model(x) < target($target_sample) for x in $model_samples )
  1.870 μs (0 allocations: 0 bytes)
1248
```

Comment: I apologize for my ignorance, but could you provide me with the documentation on the `$` operator? When I execute the operation alone, I get the following error: `syntax: "$" expression outside quote around REPL[192]:1.`

Comment: https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/metaprogramming/#man-expression-interpolation

Comment: You need to load `BenchmarkTools` package. The `$` operator is specific to @btime macro and makes the type of variables known at the @btime  context so you are not measuring the time to sort out variable types (important in micro-benchmarking).

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned above, you want to avoid allocating.  You can also avoid allocating the `model_samples` array on each iteration by pre-allocating it and calling `rand!`:

```
julia> K = 10^4; model_samples = zeros(K); d = Normal(0, 1);

julia> @btime count(model.(rand(Normal(0, 1), $K)) .< target($target_sample)); # your version
  41.462 μs (5 allocations: 83.72 KiB)

julia> @btime count(x -> model(x) < target($target_sample), rand(Normal(0, 1), $K)); # allocate rand array, no other allocations
  36.400 μs (2 allocations: 78.17 KiB)

julia> @btime count(x -> model(x) < target($target_sample), rand!(Normal(0, 1), $model_samples)); # use pre-allocated array
  28.789 μs (0 allocations: 0 bytes)

julia> @btime count(x -> model(x) < target($target_sample), randn!($model_samples)); # use randn!
  22.882 μs (0 allocations: 0 bytes)
```

Note also that `randn` is faster than `rand(Normal(0, 1))`.